# Converting a Uniform distribution to Poisson distribution

Tags: c, algorithm, distribution, probability, poisson

I have to write a C program to convert a uniform distribution of random numbers (say from 0 to 1) to a poisson distribution. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you limited to a single uniform, i.e., inversion, or allowed multiple U's?  Your wording sounds like you want a single, but the only techniques I know for the Poisson require multiple U's.

Answer (score 3):

Use GSL, the Gnu Scientific Library. There's a function called [gsl_ran_poisson](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/The-Poisson-Distribution.html):

> This function returns a random integer from the Poisson distribution with mean mu.
>   The probability distribution for Poisson variates is,
>   p(k) = {\mu^k \over k!} \exp(-\mu)
>   for k >= 0.

Otherwise, look at the code and copy the ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to write a C program that can sample a random number from the Poisson Distribution, given a random number in U(0,1).

Generally, this is done by taking the inverse CDF of the number from U(0,1). For discrete distributions like Poisson, one first transforms it to a continuous distribution by assuming that the CDF function is smooth between the integer points, and then we apply appropriate approximations (floor function).

The book **Numerical Recipes in C++** (3rd Ed) has the complete explanation and C++ code as well. sec 7.3.12, page 372.